# Unable to get the value in the shell variable

Tags: shell, unix

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5
    do
        echo "hello world"> $i
    done
    v = echo $?
    if [ $v -eq 0 ]; then
     echo " Completed"
    else
     echo "Not completed"
    fi
```

Unable to get the value in v = echo s?, due to this if condition always fails

Comment: Several errors: to set variables from a command you use `var=$(command)`, with no spaces around `=`. Then, `echo "hello world" > $i` will output to a file named $i, not a variable.

Comment: Don't forget that you MUST NOT have spaces around `=` when assigning variables in shell.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong logic use just this (direct assignation):

```
v=$?
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `v = echo $?`

Either write

```
v=`echo $?`
```

OR

```
v=$?
```